# How the voltage source and resistance got shorted out by the switch?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In the following solved problem, it is written that voltage source and resistance have been shorted out by the switch. I am unable to understand this.

[image: soled problem[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Examine this simple circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRU1sg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is open there is a voltage difference between point A and B and between B and C. Hence the current will flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBhOWo.png)</sup>

But after you closed the switch we shorted the pin B with pin C.
Shorted means that points B and C are electrically common and therefore no voltage may exist between them. The B and C becomes one point, therefore, no current can flow via R2 resistor ( all current will flow through the "short" ).